# SQL Server: Why isn't PWDCOMPARE() working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, hash

I am trying to match a password for the database users defined in `database/security/users` with the following query.

```
select 
    PWDCOMPARE(N'plain_password', password_hash)     -- 0
from sys.sql_logins 
where name = 'user'
```

It results in 0, where the correct password is provided. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it a SQL login?

Comment: @RogerWolf What do you mean by SQL login?

Comment: @DaleBurrell It has an actual value. I am using the same password to log in the ERP system, but I cannot match it. The passwords and users are for the actual database, they are not in an ERP user table.

Comment: I think the answer can only be that you don't have the correct password. The following works: `declare @HashedPassword varbinary(128); set @HashedPassword = PWDENCRYPT (N'plain_password'); select PWDCOMPARE(N'plain_password', @HashedPassword);`

Comment: @DaleBurrell That's what's so frustrating... I 100% have the correct password.

Comment: Try using the correct password in my code and see if the hash is the same as in SQL server.

Comment: @DaleBurrell The thing is, `PWDENCRYPT()` provides a different hash each time, which can only be compared with `PWDCOMPARE(),` which doesn't want to cooperate. :)

Comment: Thats very odd!

Comment: >>>users defined in database/security/users<<< you should use LOGINS and not USERS in your query. And these should be only SQL users, NOT Windows logins

Comment: @sepupic I apologize, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain a bit more? What do you mean by use LOGINS and not USERS? What are SQL users and not Windows logins?

Comment: When your login looks like LOGIN1, it's SQL Server login. When it looks like SomeDomain\SomeAccount, it's Windows login. SQL Server stores the hash of password only for SQL Server logins

Comment: User <> Login, you can have login LOGIN1, but the corresponding user is NOT LOGIN1, but USER1, created with statement CREATE USER USER1 FROM LOGIN LOGIN1. I said that when you write your query that searches in sys.sql_logins, the name of LOGIN, not the USER should be passed in